# Can't insert decimal value with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, insert, pdo, decimal

I've been trawling the web for hours now and trying different methods, and I can't work out why PDO can't insert any row where one of the values contains a decimal.

For example, if the value entered into the cost field has no decimal value then it works fine. But anything like with a decimal and it just ignores the whole row.

200 works, even 200.00 works. But things like 39.99 don't.

Here's the code:

```
$invoice_id = $db->lastInsertId('id');

$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
$item_qty = $_POST['item_qty'];
$item_cost = $_POST['item_cost'];
$item_vat = $_POST['item_vat'];

for($i = 0; $i < count($item_name); $i++) {
$item_query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO hm_invoice_items(invoice, item, qty, amount, vat) VALUES(:invoice, :item, :qty, :amount, :vat)");
$item_query->bindParam(":invoice", $invoice_id);
$item_query->bindParam(":item", $item_name[$i]);
$item_query->bindParam(":qty", $item_qty[$i]);
$item_query->bindParam(":amount", $item_cost[$i]);
$item_query->bindParam(":vat", $item_vat[$i]);

if (!$item_query->execute())
    {
        die(showMessage("There has been a problem adding the invoice items.", "Error!"));
    }
}
```

A var_dump tells me that the insert query is receiving the values, but it does not like dealing with decimals.

Comment: ignores how? you get your error message? you should be at least outputting the mysql error message, instead of just saying "there has been a problem".

Comment: Is your column of the type DECIMAL?

Comment: Why you're using `$item_name[$i]` instead of `$_POST['item_name'][$i]`? Is there a benefit?

Comment: Yes, it throws up the error. I can't seem to get PDO error messages to work? And yes, column type is DECIMAL(19,2).

Comment: `$db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );` after connect to  get PDO error messages to work

Comment: @YourCommonSense - I also get `Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )` from every insert.

Answer (score 0):

There could be an issue with decimal separator.
When debugging such cases it's **essential** to `var_dump()` e-ve-ry-thing!
Why don't you var_dump your values for the closer inspection?
Why didn't you play with decimals only, without POST, without other values?

A question titled "Can't insert decimal value with PDO" should contain short reproduceable code with decimal value present to readers and the result.
Judging by indirect measures will do no help for you and - especially - won't bring you help from strangers.

"var_dump your values" means every suspicious value, like

```
var_dump($item_cost[$i]);
```

inside your loop
if you get no output - then there is empty value, so, no wonder nothing inserted.

By the way, you're binding apparently decimal `item_cost` value to apparently integer `amount` field. Is it a typo?

But again - where is a certain reproduceable proofcode contains one insert query, one hardcoded decimal value and one result? Ugh - and table definition of course.

Comment: For some reason I am getting nothing from var_dump or PDO errors.

Comment: When trying to insert an item with the cost 2000 and one with the cost 39.99, the var_dump on the cost field returns string(4) "2000" string(5) "39.99". And the db column is called amount, its just the way I've done it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
$item_query->bindParam(":amount", floatval($item_cost[$i]));
```

At least it works for me when I deal with MySQL decimal data type with PDO.

Answer (score -1):

Use the following to display the content of **all** the values POSTed to your PHP script:

```
print_r($_POST);
```